# Chromatic adaptation transform

Tags: color-space

This is, not strictly, a programming question, but it is prompted by a programming task, so I'll ask it here.
RGB Chromatic adaptation is accomplished as follows:  A scaled and gamma-converted **RGB** vector is multiplied by a 3x3 matrix, **M**, whose terms are a function of the chromaticity coordinates and white point coordinates of the colorspace in question, **X<sub>S</sub>Y<sub>S</sub>Z<sub>S</sub>**, to obtain an **XYZ** vector.  A 3x3 adaptation matrix based in part upon a new **XYZ** white point, **X<sub>D</sub>Y<sub>D</sub>Z<sub>D</sub>** (there are various sets of coefficients proposed, beyond the scope of this question),  then multiplies **XYZ** to obtain a chromatically adapted vector, **X'Y'Z'**.  Then, **X'Y'Z'** is multiplied by an inverse matrix, **M<sup>-1</sup>**, to return a new vector, **R'G'B'**.
My question is this:
**M** was calculated using the original **X<sub>S</sub>Y<sub>S</sub>Z<sub>S</sub>** white point.  Is **M<sup>-1</sup>** the inverse of the original **M**, or is a new **M<sup>-1</sup>** reflecting the updated **X<sub>D</sub>Y<sub>D</sub>Z<sub>D</sub>** white point used?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing multiple things together which make it hard to get a good understanding as you are concatenating the *RGB* to *XYZ* conversion with the *VonKries chromatic adaptation*. While is possible to perform the entire transformation with a single matrix, i.e. linear transformation, it is easier to implement more granular steps.

*VonKries chromatic adaptation* requires you to have the following data:

- The sample colour you want to chromatically adapt, i.e. your *RGB* colour.
- The test illuminant colour your sample is viewed under, i.e. *XYZ_S* tristimulus values.
- The reference illuminant colour you want to chromatically adapt your sample to, i.e. *XYZ_D* tristimulus values.

I would suggest to first perform the conversion of your sample from *RGB* to *XYZ*. The matrix converting from *RGB* to *XYZ*, *M_NPM* is given by your RGB colourspace, its called the *Normalised Primary Matrix* (its computation is out of the scope of the question).

You can then compute the *chromatic adaptation* matrix *M* from *XYZ_S* to *XYZ_D* as per [Bruce Lindbloom](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_ChromAdapt.html).

Then take the dot product between the *chromatic adaptation* matrix *M* and your sample *XYZ* tristimulus values.

Finally, convert back to *RGB* by using *M_NPM-1* or any relevant inverse matrix suitable to your use case.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, then, *M_NPM-1* is simply the inverse of *M_NPM* ?

Comment: Yes! So in that particular case you have pretty much implemented a white balancing algorithm, ALA Adobe Lightroom, staying in the same working RGB colourspace but picking a different colour temperature for the illuminant. For some other applications, chromatic adaptation is required to ensure that whites stay white under the new illuminant. Typical case is converting between two colourspaces that have different whitepoints/illuminants, e.g. sRGB D65 to ProPhoto D50.

Answer (score 0):

an example of what I had in mind:  http://www.waysidehealth.com/Projects/color/colorMatrixGenerator.html